# Can prime numbers be defined formally like this

Tags: prime-numbers

We can say that $p$ is prime if and only if :

$$p\ne 1$$ 
$$p\space is\space prime \leftrightarrow \left\{(1|p)\wedge(p|p)\wedge\forall i\space2\leq i\leq p-1 (p\equiv r(mod\space i),r\neq0\right),(p,r)\in N\}$$

$$Edit: $$

$$p\ne 1$$ 
$$p\space is\space prime \leftrightarrow \left\{(\forall i\space2\leq i\leq p-1 (i\not\mid p)\right),(p,i)\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}\}$$

Comment: The statements $1|p$ and $p|p$ hold for every $p\in Z^+$ so you can ignore them.

Comment: Also another problem with your definition is that $1$ happens to be a prime number

Comment: Can this be corrected if I say $1$ is not a prime number, and $p,r \in N$?

Comment: yes if you add $p\not=1$ then it's fine.

Comment: Indicating that $p$ has a non-zero remainder $\mod{i}$, i.e. upon division by $i$, is equivalently stated in the more traditional manner, $i\not\mid p$.

Comment: Also, for natural numbers $p$, the statements $1\mid p$ and $p\mid p$ are superfluous, as such is true of all natural numbers.

Comment: @Yanko 1 is not prime.

Comment: @Did That's what I meant. I mentioned that $p=1$ satisfies the conditions in the OP.

Comment: Another characterization of primes that generalizes well to rings other than $\mathbb{Z}$ is that $p$ is prime if whenever $p$ divides $ab$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$.

Comment: What is your *real* question?  Why would you ever want to define primes in this way when perfectly good, and well-understood, definitions abound?

Comment: I wanted to define them formally and concisely using quantifiers , because every time I don't like writing a whole sentence just to say that a number is prime , it's just for fun.

Comment: Why do you keep $p\ne1$ outside of the RHS of the definition?